# RegExp().exec() method returns null value in ie11

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the `RegExp().exec()` this method works well in chrome and edge but not working in IE11 and its lower version.

Eg:

```
regExp = "^(\d\d?)(\/)(\d\d?)(\/)(\d{4})$"
value = "1/1/2018"

match = new RegExp(regExp).exec(value);  //returns null value in ie11
```

The above RegExp is converted into /^(\d\d?)(/)(\d\d?)(/)(\d{4})$/ as result of new RegExp(regExp) but still getting null value. please check the image below
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssFIa.jpg)

Comment: And this works just fine in IE: `console.log(/^(\d\d?)(\/)(\d\d?)(\/)(\d{4})$/.exec("1/1/2018"))`

Comment: Because you failed to define backslashes in the string literal. `console.log(new RegExp(regExp).source)` shows `^(dd?)(\/)(dd?)(\/)(d{4})$`. Use a regex literal, `/^(\d\d?)(\/)(\d\d?)(\/)(\d{4})$/`.

Comment: The code you’ve put in the question should produce `null` in every browser. Did you maybe run something slightly different in Chrome and Edge?

Comment: Just saw this exactly the same question, yesterday ..? Nope, it was [2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699472/does-ie11-have-support-for-regexp).

Comment: @Teemu, please share that link if possible.

Comment: ?? It is shared in my comment above.